# How to install .ipa for a removed app to retrieve data from iTunes

Tags: itunes

I have an iPa file for an app that was removed from app store , I need to install that on iPhone and then restore the data from a backup from iTunes backup , so I can save my data ,

Please tell me how I can do that .

Regards
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

To install that .ipa file, you need to sign in with your apple id that previously purchased or downloaded (Provided you already possessed the .ipa file).